# Should I save temporary data in $form_state or in my form class?

Tags: forms, 8

As far as I can see, there are two ways of storing temporary data when working with complex forms in Drupal 8.

1. `$form_state->set('key', 'value')`. The value ends up in $form_state['storage']['value'], and I can use it other places because it is passed around from function to function.
2. Make a non-static property inside `class MyForm extends FormBase`. The value is also accessible everywhere I need it, since all of the form functions are in one class.

After browsing through a lot of core `EntityForm` code today, it seems that both are used! Is any of the above necessarily "better" or more in line with "The Drupal Way"?

Related question: It seems that there is a `1:1` mapping between an instance of `MyForm` and the `$form_state` variable. Why then, is `$form_state` not implemented as a non-static class property? Then it wouldn't be necessary to pass it from function to function. The same can be asked of the `$form` variable.

Comment: #1 is the traditional method with the Form API and probably is more compatible with AJAXy stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the storage in `$form_state` can be cached, the class property can't. So if you build a multistep form you would need to use the first option.

And a validate or submit function is not necessarily in the same class or in no class at all if it is defined in a hook. This also answers the related question.

Comment: Indeed ... I tested this, and it seems that the instance of `MyForm` loses its properties, while `$form_state['storage']` keeps its values.